# Sum of one, two, and three squares

Tags: number-theory

If a square $n^2$ can be written as the sum of two nonzero squares as well as the sum of three nonzero squares, then can we conclude that it can be written as the sum of any number of nonzero squares up to $n^2 - 14$ nonzero squares?

Example: $13^2 = 12^2 + 5^2 = 12^2 + 4^2 + 3^2$. But also $13^2 = 11^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 + 4^2$ and $13^2 = 12^2 + 4^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 + 1^2$ etc up to $13^2 = 3^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 + .. + 1^2$.

Comment: do you include $0^2$ as a legal summand?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: $3^2$ can not be written as the sum of two squares. Same for $7^2$ and $11^2$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Of course $0$ isn't allowed, otherwise the problem is trivial

Comment: @Johannes, that's what I was pointing to

Comment: @labbhattacharjee But then you are mis-reading the question. The question is, "If $n^2$ can be written as the sum of two squares and the sum of three square, then can we conclude..."

Comment: @Johannes It would be better to start with the question, rather than bury it after a numerical example. I think that is why people are being confused - reading the example instead of the question.

Comment: Good point. Have changed the order.

Comment: The next one to try would be $17^2=15^2+8^2=12^2 +9^2+8^2$

Comment: $17^2 = 11^2 + 10^2 + 8^2 + 2^2$

Comment: Or $17^2=16^2+4^2+4^2+1^2$. But do you get all the possible later values?

Comment: A quick thing to note is that if $n^2=a^2+b^2$ with $a,b\neq 0$, then $n$ can be written in the form $n=d(u^2+v^2)$ where $d,u,v\neq 0$.  But then $$n^2=d^2\left(u^4 + 2u^2v^2 + v^2\right) = (du^2)^2 +(duv)^2 + (duv)^2 + (dv)^2$$ So $n^2$ is the sum of four non-zero squares. So you get four non-zero squares if you had two non-zero squares.

Comment: Also, if $n^2=a^2+b^2$ then (at least) one of $a,b$ is even, and then we have (say) $n^2=4a_0^2+b^2$, so we get five. Not sure how to get six.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true.

All positive integers that are not the sum of four nonzero squares are known, see [FOUR](http://oeis.org/A000534) and [LAGRANGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#Uniqueness). These are the eight odd number $1,3,5,9,11,17,29,41$ and the infinite families $2 \cdot 4^t, \; \; 6 \cdot 4^t, \; \; 14 \cdot 4^t.$ Out of the list, the squares are $1,9;$ of course $1$ is not the sum of two or three nonzero squares, while $9=4+4+1$ but is not the sum of two nonzero squares. This gives a quick and dirty way to show 1,2,3 nonzero squares implies 4 nonzero squares. A more elegant method, by Thomas Andrews, is in comment above.

All numbers, square or not, larger than 33 are the sum of five  nonzero squares, see [FIVE](http://oeis.org/A047701). All numbers, square or not, larger than 19 are the sum of six  nonzero squares, see [SIX](http://oeis.org/A123120).

Now, we have some $n^2 \geq 36, $ and we are told that $n^2$ is also the sum of two nonzero squares and of three nonzero squares. ThomasAndrews shows above how  $n^2$ is the sum of four nonzero squares. So far, we have 1,2,3,4,5,6 covered.

Now, take any integer $M$ with $ 20 \leq M < n^2.$ We are told that $M$ is the sum of six nonzero squares. Then add in $n^2 - M$ copies of 1. The result is a summation of $n^2$ as $n^2 - M + 6$ nonzero squares. Here $$ 6 < n^2 - M + 6 \leq n^2 - 14. $$

The numbers up to 100,000 that are nonzero squares, and are also the sum of two nonzero squares and of three nonzero squares are

```
         169 = 13^2
         225 = 3^2 * 5^2
         289 = 17^2
         625 = 5^4
         676 = 2^2 * 13^2
         841 = 29^2
         900 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5^2
        1156 = 2^2 * 17^2
        1225 = 5^2 * 7^2
        1369 = 37^2
        1521 = 3^2 * 13^2
        1681 = 41^2
        2025 = 3^4 * 5^2
        2500 = 2^2 * 5^4
        2601 = 3^2 * 17^2
        2704 = 2^4 * 13^2
        2809 = 53^2
        3025 = 5^2 * 11^2
        3364 = 2^2 * 29^2
        3600 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^2
        3721 = 61^2
        4225 = 5^2 * 13^2
        4624 = 2^4 * 17^2
        4900 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 7^2
        5329 = 73^2
        5476 = 2^2 * 37^2
        5625 = 3^2 * 5^4
        6084 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 13^2
        6724 = 2^2 * 41^2
        7225 = 5^2 * 17^2
        7569 = 3^2 * 29^2
        7921 = 89^2
        8100 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2
        8281 = 7^2 * 13^2
        9025 = 5^2 * 19^2
        9409 = 97^2
       10000 = 2^4 * 5^4
       10201 = 101^2
       10404 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 17^2
       10816 = 2^6 * 13^2
       11025 = 3^2 * 5^2 * 7^2
       11236 = 2^2 * 53^2
       11881 = 109^2
       12100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 11^2
       12321 = 3^2 * 37^2
       12769 = 113^2
       13225 = 5^2 * 23^2
       13456 = 2^4 * 29^2
       13689 = 3^4 * 13^2
       14161 = 7^2 * 17^2
       14400 = 2^6 * 3^2 * 5^2
       14884 = 2^2 * 61^2
       15129 = 3^2 * 41^2
       15625 = 5^6
       16900 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 13^2
       18225 = 3^6 * 5^2
       18496 = 2^6 * 17^2
       18769 = 137^2
       19600 = 2^4 * 5^2 * 7^2
       20449 = 11^2 * 13^2
       21025 = 5^2 * 29^2
       21316 = 2^2 * 73^2
       21904 = 2^4 * 37^2
       22201 = 149^2
       22500 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5^4
       23409 = 3^4 * 17^2
       24025 = 5^2 * 31^2
       24336 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 13^2
       24649 = 157^2
       25281 = 3^2 * 53^2
       26896 = 2^4 * 41^2
       27225 = 3^2 * 5^2 * 11^2
       28561 = 13^4
       28900 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 17^2
       29929 = 173^2
       30276 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 29^2
       30625 = 5^4 * 7^2
       31684 = 2^2 * 89^2
       32400 = 2^4 * 3^4 * 5^2
       32761 = 181^2
       33124 = 2^2 * 7^2 * 13^2
       33489 = 3^2 * 61^2
       34225 = 5^2 * 37^2
       34969 = 11^2 * 17^2
       36100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 19^2
       37249 = 193^2
       37636 = 2^2 * 97^2
       38025 = 3^2 * 5^2 * 13^2
       38809 = 197^2
       40000 = 2^6 * 5^4
       40804 = 2^2 * 101^2
       41209 = 7^2 * 29^2
       41616 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 17^2
       42025 = 5^2 * 41^2
       43264 = 2^8 * 13^2
       44100 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7^2
       44944 = 2^4 * 53^2
       46225 = 5^2 * 43^2
       47524 = 2^2 * 109^2
       47961 = 3^2 * 73^2
       48400 = 2^4 * 5^2 * 11^2
       48841 = 13^2 * 17^2
       49284 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 37^2
       50625 = 3^4 * 5^4
       51076 = 2^2 * 113^2
       52441 = 229^2
       52900 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 23^2
       53824 = 2^6 * 29^2
       54289 = 233^2
       54756 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 13^2
       55225 = 5^2 * 47^2
       56644 = 2^2 * 7^2 * 17^2
       57600 = 2^8 * 3^2 * 5^2
       58081 = 241^2
       59536 = 2^4 * 61^2
       60025 = 5^2 * 7^4
       60516 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 41^2
       61009 = 13^2 * 19^2
       62500 = 2^2 * 5^6
       65025 = 3^2 * 5^2 * 17^2
       66049 = 257^2
       67081 = 7^2 * 37^2
       67600 = 2^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
       68121 = 3^4 * 29^2
       70225 = 5^2 * 53^2
       71289 = 3^2 * 89^2
       72361 = 269^2
       72900 = 2^2 * 3^6 * 5^2
       73984 = 2^8 * 17^2
       74529 = 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2
       75076 = 2^2 * 137^2
       75625 = 5^4 * 11^2
       76729 = 277^2
       78400 = 2^6 * 5^2 * 7^2
       78961 = 281^2
       81225 = 3^2 * 5^2 * 19^2
       81796 = 2^2 * 11^2 * 13^2
       82369 = 7^2 * 41^2
       83521 = 17^4
       84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
       84681 = 3^2 * 97^2
       85264 = 2^4 * 73^2
       85849 = 293^2
       87025 = 5^2 * 59^2
       87616 = 2^6 * 37^2
       88804 = 2^2 * 149^2
       89401 = 13^2 * 23^2
       90000 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^4
       91809 = 3^2 * 101^2
       93025 = 5^2 * 61^2
       93636 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 17^2
       96100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 31^2
       97344 = 2^6 * 3^2 * 13^2
       97969 = 313^2
       98596 = 2^2 * 157^2
       99225 = 3^4 * 5^2 * 7^2
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know the five and six theorems.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, took that out, then corrected the lower bounds for 5 and 6, which i had incorrectly switched.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. (You guys are quick!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because [all numbers can be written as the sum of four squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem).

Comment: I think he is insisting on nonzero squares.

Comment: It is still true by induction, right? ... (Oh, but I didn't handle the upper limit...)

Comment: It's not clear how to ensure non-zero values via the induction, however. @DanBrumleve It seems like you should be able to, but there is some trickiness involved.

Comment: A summand of the form $8n+7$ will require four non-zero squares