# Determining the number of ways a number can be written as sum of three squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, computational-mathematics, sums-of-squares

I was going through [Erich Friedman's "What's Special About This Number?"](https://erich-friedman.github.io/numbers.html) and there some numbers are classified based on the number of ways we can write them as sum of squares. I want to prove the following claim by Friedman:

> 129 is the smallest number that can be written as the sum of 3 squares
> in 4 ways.

Indeed, as given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/129_%28number%29),
$$11^2+2^2+2^2 = 10^2+5^2+2^2 = 8^2+8^2+1^2 = 8^2+7^2+4^2 = 129$$
So what remains to prove is that this is the smallest such number.

> Is it possible to write a proof for this fact using some insights
> along with brute force/cases? How can we solve this problem using *only*
> brute-force?

Also, since I know the proof of [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/223939). I am also curious to know:

> How can we determine the number of ways we can write a non-negative
> integer which satisfies Legendre's three-square theorem as sum of
> three squares?

**Edit1:** Related discussions on MathOverflow:

- [Is there a simple way to compute the number of ways to write a positive integer as the sum of three squares?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer): Note that this is not answer of my question since $r_k(n)$ counts the number of representations of $n$ by $k$ squares, allowing zeros and distinguishing signs and order.
- [Efficient computation of integer representation as sum of three squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104322/efficient-computation-of-integer-representation-as-sum-of-three-squares)

**Edit2:** Related discussions on ComputerScience.SE

- [Listing integers as the sum of three squares $m=x^2+y^2+z^2$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33887/63553)

**Edit3:** Related discussions on Mathematics.SE

- [When is a rational number a sum of three squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1200794)
- [Why can't this number be written as a sum of three squares of rationals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527748)
- [Sum of one, two, and three squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437919/214604)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck nothing better possible?

Comment: Find the number. This is one task. You can use brute force all the possible options.  If you find a parameterization of the solutions of this equation.  That's another problem.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck but not any number can be represented as 4 ways.

Comment: I also want to know how to find all ways of representing a number in sum of some squares

Comment: we can find some solutions, if not all, by solving some quadratic equations using triangular numbers as explained in the link below but I don't have the proof that we will find all of them: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070691/on-the-number-of-ways-of-writing-an-integer-as-a-sum-of-3-squares-using-triangul

Comment: @user25406 this approach appears to be promising.

Comment: There is the following formula for the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of two squares: $4 \sum_{m | n} \chi_4(n)$, where $\chi_4$ is the conductor of order 4. I wonder if this could be generalized to your question.

Comment: @JRichey Can you please point to some proof/discussion on this formula? I was able to find this discussion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181336/the-number-of-ways-of-writing-an-integer-as-a-sum-of-two-squares

Comment: I read this in a book on Sieve theory, though I can't seem to find the book. The formula comes from the connection between Dirichlet characters (which are related to the Legendre/Jacobi symbol) and sums of squares.

Comment: Link to Erich Friedman's work is now broken. Updated link: https://erich-friedman.github.io/numbers.html

Comment: @RahulMadhavan Thanks! Updated the link in the post.

Answer (score 5):

Legendre gave the following answer, which he could not prove (Gauss gave the first proof of the 3-squares theorem). For the sake of simplicity I will only cover the case of numbers $c \equiv 5 \bmod 8$. In this case consider the equivalence classes of forms with discriminant $-4c$; like Legendre, we will consider equivalence with respect to the action of GL$_2({\mathbb Z})$. Let $P$ denote the form classes that represent primes $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, and $Q$ those that represent primes $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. Then the number of classes $P$ is equal to that of classes $Q$, and to the number of ways in which $c$ can be written as a sum of three squares.

If $c = 29$, the classes $P$ are $x^2 + 29y^2$ and $5x^2 + 2xy + 6y^2$, and these correspond to the two distinct ways of writing $29$ as a sum of three squares: $29 = 0^2 + 2^2 + 5^2 = 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2$.

Legendre conjectured similar formulas for other values of $c$, which were later proved by Gauss, but using classes with respect to the action of SL$_2({\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: If $n=5\mod8$, the squares are $0,4,1\mod8$, so all distinct, so 6 ways to assign to $x^2,y^2,z^2$. If none is 0, then there are 8 options for signs of $x, y, z$, so 48 values of $(x,y,z)$. If one is 0, 24. $r(n)=12H(-4n)$ but how do the classes group into 2s and 4s and how do these groups correspond to values of $(x,y,z)$? $D=-4*29$ for the 6 classes <1,0,29>;<2,2,15>;<$3,\pm2,10$>;<$5,\pm2,6$>; how do these correspond to $29=5^2+2^2+0=4^2+3^2+2^2$? How do the 6 classes <1,0,45>; <2,2,23>; <3,0,15>; <5,0,9>; <6,6,9>; <7,4,7> of $D=-4*45$ correspond to $45=6^2+3^2+0=5^2+4^2+2^2$?

Answer (score -1):

For the system of equations.

$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=x_4^2+x_5^2+x_6^2=x_7^2+x_8^2+x_9^2=x_{10}^2+x_{11}^2+x_{12}^2$$

Solutions can be parameterized.

$$x_1=a(y^2+z^2+n^2)(p^2+s^2+n^2)(k^2+t^2+n^2)$$

$$x_2=b(y^2+z^2+n^2)(p^2+s^2+n^2)(k^2+t^2+n^2)$$

$$x_3=c(y^2+z^2+n^2)(p^2+s^2+n^2)(k^2+t^2+n^2)$$

$$x_4=(ay^2-2byn+az^2-2czn-an^2)(p^2+s^2+n^2)(k^2+t^2+n^2)$$

$$x_5=(bz^2-2cyz-by^2-2ayn+bn^2)(p^2+s^2+n^2)(k^2+t^2+n^2)$$

$$x_6=(cy^2-2byz-cz^2-2azn+cn^2)(p^2+s^2+n^2)(k^2+t^2+n^2)$$

$$x_7=(ap^2-2bpn+as^2-2csn-an^2)(y^2+z^2+n^2)(k^2+t^2+n^2)$$

$$x_8=(bs^2-2cps-bp^2-2apn+bn^2)(y^2+z^2+n^2)(k^2+t^2+n^2)$$

$$x_9=(cp^2-2bps-cs^2-2asn+cn^2)(y^2+z^2+n^2)(k^2+t^2+n^2)$$

$$x_{10}=(ak^2-2bkn+at^2-2ctn-an^2)(y^2+z^2+n^2)(p^2+s^2+n^2)$$

$$x_{11}=(bt^2-2ckt-bk^2-2akn+bn^2)(y^2+z^2+n^2)(p^2+s^2+n^2)$$

$$x_{12}=(ck^2-2bkt-ct^2-2atn+cn^2)(y^2+z^2+n^2)(p^2+s^2+n^2)$$

It is interesting that such triples can be too much. The formula can be increased to any number. That is the same to write not only for 4 partitions, but for any number. The main thing that all the variables were not identical to each other.

Comment: Can you please give at least an outline of how one should write proof for 129 being smallest such number using this parametrization?

Comment: @individ, can you please post your derivation or a link to it. I think it is important to show how you got this parametrization, especially to those among us (I am one of them) who don't have the knowledge to derive it for themselves.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like:

```
check=new Array();
for (i=1;i<12;i++)
for (j=i;j<12;j++)
for (k=j;k<12;k++) {
n=i*i+j*j+k*k;
if (!check[n]) check[n]=0;
check[n]++;
}
for (a=0;a<check.length;a++)
if (check[a]>=4) console.log(a);
```

which proves $129$ is the smallest such number, followed by:

$$134=11^2+3^2+2^2=10^2+5^2+3^2=9^2+7^2+2^2=7^2+7^2+6^2$$

You can determine the number of representations by $3$ squares by subtracting squares from $N$, and using $\sum_\limits{x\le \sqrt{N}} r_2(N-x^2)$, where $r_2$ is the [sum of (two) squares function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html).

Comment: Did you read the Edit1 above stating that these counting functions also count the number is permutations and sign changes (which I don't want)?

Comment: somewhere there is a formula for sum of two squares where zeroes, sign and order aren't counted - for example 16 doesn't count, but I can't find it just now. $r_2$ is the best we've got at the moment I think for the number of such numbers.