# New Year 2017 Riddle (3 quadratic Diophanitine equations)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

What is the smallest prime number n which can be formulated with all of the
three following integer equations?
$$u^2 +  4^2 \cdot v^2 = n$$
$$w^2 +  9^2 \cdot x^2 = n$$
$$y^2 + 11^2 \cdot z^2 = n$$

Comment: The three sums can only be equal if $b=0$ but in that case $n$ is not a prime. If you mean that $a,b$ are different for each equation then you should state that better,

Comment: I'm guessing that these are just the forms in which $n$ can be expressed - i.e it's not the same $a,b$ in all the equations.

Comment: $127$ looks good

Comment: @Euler_Salter $127$ can't be written in the form $a^2 + 11^2 b^2$. The answer is actually $2017$ (what else?)

Comment: I assumed that $2017$ was going to be the answer!

Comment: I actually just shouted a number. Funnily enough I guessed all three non-zero digits

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069687/representation-of-a-number-as-a-sum-of-squares/2070383#2070383

Answer (score 4):

Using the Theorem:

> If a prime can be expressed as sum of two squares then the representation is unique.
>   [Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/719700/305474)

Then we have that the three expressions are the same.

Then for minimize $n$ we need find a prime  that can be expressed as any of this forms:
$$4^2\cdot 11^2 r^2+9^2 j^2$$ or $$4^2\cdot 9^2 l^2+11^2 f^2$$
But $36^2+11^2=1417$ isn't a prime and by coincidences of the life $44^2+9^2=2017$ is a prime number. We are done.

Comment: I like this theorem.

Comment: I don't understand  "we need find a prime such that $4^2⋅11^2r^2+9^2j^2$
or $4^2\cdot 9^2l^2+11^2f^2$".

Comment: We need a prime that can be represented as any of this forms. Did you understand?

Comment: Now I do. I suggest you to edit your answer to make it more comprehensible.

Comment: I suppose that $9^211^2p^2+4^2q^2$ could have worked.  But then the first term is at least $9801$.

Answer (score -1):

$$ax_1^2+bx_2^2=ax_3^2+bx_4^2=ax_5^2+bx_6^2$$

The solution is easy to write.

$$x_1=t(bp^2+ak^2)(bs^2+ak^2)$$

$$x_2=y(bp^2+ak^2)(bs^2+ak^2)$$

$$x_3=((bp^2-ak^2)t-2bpky)(bs^2+ak^2)$$

$$x_4=((bp^2-ak^2)y+2apkt)(bs^2+ak^2)$$

$$x_5=((bs^2-ak^2)t-2bsky)(bp^2+ak^2)$$

$$x_6=((bs^2-ak^2)y+2askt)(bp^2+ak^2)$$

Here the representation of 3 options, but it is easy to see that can be written in the form of a combination with any number of options.