# can $z=x^2 + y^2$ have more than 2 different solutions when $z$ is given and $x,y,z$ are all integers?

Tags: number-theory

For instance $z=50$ has two solutions: $(x,y)=(1,7)$  and $(x,y)=(5,5)$.
  $z=125$ has two solutions $(x,y)=(10,5)$   and $(x,y)=(11,2)$.
Just fumbling around, I have not found any $z$ that has 3 or more solutions.
Is there a systematic way to generate solutions?

I have since made a C program to check every number between 1000 and 10000 and
found about 10% decompose into 2 squares,quite a few that decompose into 3 squares,  a lesser amount into 4 and even a couple that are the sum of 5 squares.

Comment: If you include negative $x$ and $y$, you might get many more solutions.

Comment: To the downvoter: just because the OP didn't format his question using MathJax doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Comment: $325=10^2+15^2=1^2+18^2=6^2+17^2$. [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) describes ways to produce examples.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069687/representation-of-a-number-as-a-sum-of-squares/2070383#2070383

Comment: When you say "decompose into $3$ squares" I think you mean "decompose into $2$ squares in $3$ different ways".  The present expression sounds more like writing $z = x^2 + y^2 + w^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example:

\begin{align}
71825&=1^2+268^2\\
&=40^2+265^2\\
&=65^2+260^2\\
&=76^2+257^2\\
&=104^2+247^2\\
&=127^2+236^2\\
&=160^2+215^2\\
&=169^2+208^2\\
&=188^2+191^2
\end{align}

However the counterexample mentioned by @lulu is the smallest counterexample;
$$325=10^2+15^2=1^2+18^2=6^2+17^2$$

---

We can produce infinitely many of them by setting $p,q$ primes both $1\mod 4$, then $p^2q$ has $3$ distinct ways to write as sum of two squares. For example, $p=13$ and $q=29$, then $p^2q=4901$ has three ways to write as sum of three squares, and indeed, $$4901=70^2+1^2=26^2+65^2=49^2+50^2$$

[mathworld.wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) has an excellent page about this subject (linked by @lulu).

Answer (score 1):

Using methods of analytic number theory one can compute $r_2(n)$, the number of different ways to represent $n$ as the sum of two squares. We have
$$
r_2(n) = 4\sum_{d=1,3,...|n}(-1)^{(d-1)/2} 
 = 4\sum_{d|n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi d\right),
$$
see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html). Clearly $r_2(n)\ge 3$ for $n$ chosen accordingly in the first sum.

Answer (score 1):

My example was gotten by multiplying out $(1+2i)(2\pm3i)(1\pm i)$ to get $5\cdot13\cdot17=1105=32^2+9^2=4^2+33^2=31^2+12^2=24^2+23^2$.