# Express $355$ as a sum of three squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, sums-of-squares

**PROBLEM**

> Find all the ways to express $355$ as a sum of three squares.

**MY ATTEMPT**

By [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem), since $355$ is not of the form $n = {4^a}(8b+7)$ (for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$), then $355$ can be expressed as a sum of three squares.

WLOG, we can restrict to positive integral solutions in
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 355,$$
where $x \leq y \leq z$.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=355+%3D+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+z%5E2) gives
$$x = 7, y = 9, z = 15,$$
and
$$x = 3, y = 11, z = 15.$$

**QUESTION**

> Are these all of the solutions?

Comment: Here's a method that allows you to find all representations of an integer N as a sum of 3 squares.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070691/on-the-number-of-ways-of-writing-an-integer-as-a-sum-of-3-squares-using-triangul?noredirect=1#comment4252543_2070691

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not consider any order between $x,y,z$ here.

$x^2+y^2+z^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and since $(0,1,2)\xrightarrow{x^2}(0,1,1)$ then we can only be in the $0+0+1$ configuration, so two numbers are divisible by $3$.

$x=3a,\ y=3b$ gives $9(a^2+b^2)+z^2=355\iff z^2\equiv 4\pmod 9\iff z\equiv 2,7\pmod 9$

Since $19^2=361>355$ then only $z=2,7,11,16$ are possible.

For $a^2,b^2$ we are limited to values $0,1,4,9,16,25,36$ in the table below and it is easy to find them manually

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
z & \frac{355-z^2}9 & a^2+b^2 & x,y\\\hline
2 & 39 & \varnothing \\
7 & 34 & 9+25 & 9,15\\
11 & 26 & 1+25 & 3,15\\
16 & 11 & \varnothing \\\hline
\end{array}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is all.  It is a quick check in a spreadsheet.  We know $0 \le x \le 10$ and $11 \le z \le 18$, so put $0-10$ in a column, $11-18$ in a row and sqrt(355-left^2-up^2) in each cell.  Scan for integers and you find the solutions.  Mixed references and copy down/copy right mean you just type the formula once.