# Are there ways to generate alternative representations of a number as the sum of three squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Assume we have a positive integer $n$ which is the sum of the squares of three integers — for example,

$$
n = 451 = 15^2 + 15^2 + 1^2.
$$

As it turns out, this particular $n$ has are several other such representations, because

$$
  n = 451 = 15^2 + 15^2 + 1^2
= 21^2 + 3^2 + 1^2
= 17^2 + 9^2 + 9^2
= 19^2 + 9^2 + 3^2.
$$

I know there are ways of determining whether a given number has such a representation, [calculating how many representations a given number has](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer), and so on. What I want instead is transformations or algorithms that could be used to generate additional representations from a given one. For example, Euler gave
$$a^2+b^2+c^2 = (2m-a)^2 + (2m-b)^2 + (2m-c)^2, \qquad a+b+c=3m$$
and related relations; several mathematicians (including Bradley) have given complete solutions (a.k.a. “parameterizations“).

Does anyone know of a connected graph of solutions/equations, analogous to the Tree of Pythagoras for Pythagorean triples, which would give an algorithm by which one could move from a given three-square representation to [all] others? In particular, a way to find the representation which satisfies a particular criteria (*e.g.,* the one which contains the term with the smallest possible absolute value) would be most helpful.

I could try to build/compile it myself, but didn’t want to reinvent the wheel if it’s already been done!

Comment: I am not aware of a formula for the number of ways we can write a number as a sum of THREE perfect squares.

Comment: @Peter: I mean, for example, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer

Comment: https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~mikeh/webpapers/paper63.ps

Comment: Theorem: Every positive definite ternary quadratic form with determinant $1$ is
equivalent to a sum of three squares.

See: https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/michaud/threesquarestalk.pdf

Comment: I think it's easier to try to find the representation with the largest square. $\sqrt(451)=21.23676$. So $451=21^2 +(451-21^2)=21^2 + 10= 21^2 +3^2 +1^2$. Once you get one square, you try to write the remainder ( here $10$) as a sum of two squares.Then you move down by trying lower squares than $21$ and repeating the process ( of finding a sum of two squares). Note that $451=2*225+1=2*15^2 +1$.

Comment: (cont). When trying $20^2$ we find that $451=20^2 +51= 20^2 +(4*12+3)$. So this means you can't have a representation with $20^2$ since the remainder $51$ is of the form $4k+3$, form that doesn't admit a representation as a sum of two squares.

Comment: Euler's formulas are by rational orthogonal  transformations, see Pall 1940  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Pall_Automorphs_1940.pdf  especially formula (10)  in section 3.   I did some experiments, sent column  vector (1,15,15)   to (1,3,21)  while fixing the cross product  (45,-1,-2). Actually interchanged the first two; anyway, $$ \frac{1}{5}  \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)  $$   The next one had denominator 7.  Perhaps always prime denominator with restrictions on the primes?

Comment: To get matrix with positive determinant, better to interchange the two   given vectors and negate the cross product, the mapping being a rotation of 180 degrees around the vector that is the sum of the two givens

Comment: The answer by Zwim provides a method to find the three squares representations of a given number. See this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361586/express-355-as-a-sum-of-three-squares

Comment: @user25406: ooooooo… That link is gold. Thanks!

Comment: @user25406: The other method you suggested (i.e., finding the largest first) is known as the “greedy algorithm”, and *might* be useful… but there’s a particular reason I’m hoping to find the *smallest* square term.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: Consider following relation:

$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ac)$

Rewrite this as:

$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ac)$

This relation implies that for every $n=a^2+b^2+c^2$ there  exists a number like $a+b+c=m$. m can be some certain numbers their squares are greater than n. For example for 451 we have numbers, $22^2=484$, $23^2=529$, $25^2=625$ etc. If n is odd then m must also be odd such that $2| m^2-n$. If n is even then m must also be even.  For example for 451 only odd m are acceptable.

Suppose a is greatest number then the third equation can be :

$a\leq\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$

So we can arrange following system of Diophantine equations:

$\begin{cases} a^2+b^2+c^2=n\\a+b+c=m\\a\leq\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor \end {cases}$

For example with $n=451$, $m^2=23^2=529$, $25^2=625$, $27^2=729$, $29^2=841$, $31^2=961$, $33^2=1089$, $35^2=1225$ and $37^2=1369$ can be checked.

$a\leq \lfloor \sqrt{451}\rfloor=21 $

$25=21+3+1$

$31=19+9+3=15+15+1$

$35=17+9+9$

By brute force we may find more solutions.

Comment: @user 25406 .it was a typo. sorry.