# Number of partition of $n$ into sum of three squares, needing fast algorithm

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Does anyone know how to find number of partitions of $n$ into sum of three squares with asymtotic time complexity faster than $O(n)$ ?

I found some info on https://oeis.org/A000164, but there are an $O(n)$-algo in FORMULA section
(because we need to find all divisors of each $n-k^2$ number for compute $e(n-k^2)$) and $O(n)$-algo in MAPLE section.

Comment: I am not sure it's a fast algorithm but this method will get you all the solutions if the $n$ can be expressed as a sum of $3$ squares in more than one way.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070691/on-the-number-of-ways-of-writing-an-integer-as-a-sum-of-3-squares-using-triangul