# Gauss’s representation number of sum of three squares

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, representations-by-quadratic-forms

It is well known that the representation number of sum of three squares is related to the (form) class number of binary quadratic forms, which was proved by Gauss.

But, I could not find references to explain his motivation for this relation.

I appreciate if you teach me how Gauss recognized the relation.

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer/22655#22655

Comment: seems the reference you want is Grosswald, Representations of Integers as Sums of Squares  (1985)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068160/determining-the-number-of-ways-a-number-can-be-written-as-sum-of-three-squares?rq=1) here, with many links and the answer by Franz Lemmermeyer.